# Chrome: PDF in iframe not downloadable

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, pdf, iframe

Hi dead StackOverflow community!

I'm currently facing problems with Google Chrome 61.

I'm creating a PDF file dynamically and embed it into an iframe on a new tab. (Actually it's our customer's whish. So there is no alternative in displaying). The created PDF document is delivered by a base64 string.

While we can view the PDF without any problems it's impossible to download it via the standard viewer of Google Chrome by pressing the "Download"-Button.
On Firefox everything works as expected. On Chrome you can press the button but it has no effect.

Basically this is my html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,MY_BASE_64_STRING" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen="">
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i'm viewing the contents inside the iframe I am able to see a lot of plugins and internal Google-Code which I think is for viewing the PDF document. A lot more than Firefox offers.

Am I missing something? I haven't got such problems in Pre-60 versions of Chrome.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Mischaal

Comment: Have you found any solution?